# Copy and paste specific columns based on list on another page

Tags: vba, excel

I have a predetermined list of column headers on "Sheet2". I want to write a macro to cycle through these and search on "Sheet1" for the matching col headers and the paste them on "Sheet3".

Thank so much :)

I have come up with following so far:

```
Sub cppp() 
Range("K2").Select Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K2:K10"), Type:=xlFillDefault     

Dim lr As Long, i As Long 
lr = Range("K2").End(xlDown).Row 

For i = lr To 1 Step -1 
    If Cells(lr, 11).Value = Range("A2") Then 'STUCK 
    End If
    lr = lr - 1 
Next i 
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet or you just wanted to notify us about your intentions?

Comment: Whoops, Sorry. Early in the morning.

Comment: Sub cppp() Range("K2").Select Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K2:K10"), Type:=xlFillDefault Dim lr As Long, i As Long lr = Range("K2").End(xlDown).Row For i = lr To 1 Step -1 If Cells(lr, 11).Value = Range("A2") Then 'STUCK End If lr = lr - 1 Next i End Sub

Comment: I am trying to do it internally in one page first but with no success. My skills are rusty. Sorry and thanks for any help ya go in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you

```
Sub sample()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim sh3 As Worksheet
Dim rngLookupValues As Range
Dim rngHeaders As Range
Dim cValue As Range
Dim rngCellsToCopy As Range
Dim lngColumnToCopy As Long
Dim lngCurFirstEmptyColumn As Long

Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set sh3 = Sheets("Sheet3")
With sh2
    Set rngLookupValues = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

With sh1
    Set rngHeaders = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlToRight))
End With

For Each cValue In rngLookupValues
    lngColumnToCopy = WorksheetFunction.Match(cValue, rngHeaders, 0)

    With sh1
        Set rngCellsToCopy = .Range(.Cells(1, lngColumnToCopy), .Cells(Rows.Count, lngColumnToCopy).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With sh3
        lngCurFirstEmptyColumn = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    End With

    sh3.Cells(1, lngCurFirstEmptyColumn).Resize(rngCellsToCopy.Rows.Count).Value = rngCellsToCopy.Value
Next cValue

With sh3.Range("A1")
    If Len(.Value) < 1 Then
        .EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I stepped through it with F8 and for some reason no results. I will play around, this looks promising!

Comment: You feel free to share the link

Comment: I tried to upload to an ftp i used to use for school but I cant. Out of Ideas on how to link.

Comment: Google Drive, DropBox, Box.Com, wetransfer.com, wikisend.com, fileswap.com, MediaFire.com. All sites offer you the ability to share files, or host files for free, I think media fire doesn't even require you to sign up last time I checked. You can upload without a sign in then share a link. try one of these.

Comment: You are an amazing help but literally every site isn't allowed at work, blocked by IT. I will try to figure something out, tonight if need be. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Even Google Drive? That's a surprise. How about you just tell me what it is doing that you don't expect? I added some debug output so you can check the information, and tell me where it is pointing and where it should be. try running the updated code and check the Information in the Immediate Window (at the bottom) and see if the information matches what it should be, if not say what it says and what it should say.

Comment: After so much freaking confusing this is the one that i got working (well I as in you..). The only thing is it only coppies the headers and not the whole column. I will play around. Cheers!

Comment: User2140261 I have a follow up, I will give you a check no matter what If you answer it. Do you want me to open a new question for it? The macro only copies and pastes the headers and not the actual column data.

Comment: When it reaches the line `Debug.Print rngCellsToCopy.Address` What does it say the address is?, `sh3.Cells(1, lngCurFirstEmptyColumn).Resize(rngCellsToCopy.Rows.Count) = rngCellsToCopy` should be setting the column in Sheets 3 to the same size (same amount of rows) and the cells to copy it shuold resize it and then set every cell in that range = to every  cell in the same location in the other range

Comment: @user3010989 feel like a pain I am here to help, It helps me learn more as I help teach others at the same time problems like this help me solve similar ones in the future!! I see it as experience not problems! To see the debugging Press `CTRL+G` and It should bring you to a window called `Immediate` it is typically found at the bottom of the VBA window. once you run the code there should be text in that box, when debug.print is used it prints to there. But for now I will change the code to message box to be more easy to read! I have updated the code with `MsgBox` already try running it now

Comment: @user3010989 I just updated the code now that it is all tested, it should run nice and fast and have no issues! Give it a shot and let me know.

Comment: @simoco This was the original code to a subsequent question you answered.